# What mapping/earth controls are available for iPad app development?

Tags: google-maps, ipad, bing-maps, google-earth, virtual-earth

What mapping/earth controls are available for iPad app developer?  Is MapKit the only one?

Answer (score 1):

MapKit is the only one that comes from Apple in the sdk.

[Here is one for Bing/Virtual Earth mapping](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/blogs/maps/archive/2008/11/13/developing-virtual-earth-iphone-applications-with-objective-c.aspx)